# Alternative expression for saying "piece of someone's mind"

Tags: phrases, expression-choice

**Sentence example:**

> I am really upset and frustrated with one of my friends. So when I meet him next time around I will definitely not hold myself back and give him a piece of my mind.

What alternative expressions can I use instead of "piece of my mind"?

Comment: Note: I just altered a suggested edit that used "peace of someone's mind". "Peace of mind" is the absence of stress or anxiety. "Give someone a piece of my mind" is to harshly and aggressively criticise them because I disapprove of their actions.

Comment: Why do you feel you need an alternate expression?  The idiom is "a piece of my mind."

Comment: @Jim, maybe they want to gild the lily, to wax long, large and lyrical, to lay it on thick, to embellish and embolden by tautophrasic repetition and rhetorical rhythms. Or maybe they'd just used it once already and figured it was too strong an idiom to repeat much.

Comment: @JonHanna- Having the OP tell us why he needs an alternative mighty help us to find an acceptable one.  Incidentally, I don't think *gild the lilly* fits at all here.

Comment: @Jim, I know, I just couldn't resist a bit of lily-gilding myself (and using several synonyms when one would do would fit gilding the lily).

Answer (score 2):

You can also:

*"read him the riot act"*
*"vent your spleen"*
*"chew him out"*

> **EDIT**
>
> From [The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/read-the-riot-act.html):
>
> In English law the control of unruly citizens has usually been the
>   responsibility of local magistrates. Any group of twelve or more that
>   the authorities didn't like the look of could be deemed a 'riotous and
>   tumultuous assembly' and arrested if they didn't disperse within an
>   hour of the Riot Act being read to them by a magistrate. This seems a
>   little harsh, but in 18th century England the government was fearful
>   of Jacobite mobs who threatened to rise up and overthrow the
>   Hanoverian George I. The fear was well-founded, as supporters of the
>   deposed Stuarts did actually invade in 1715 and again in 1745. The
>   'Riot Act' was passed by the British government in 1714 and came into
>   force in 1715. The Riot Act, which was more formally called 'An act
>   for preventing tumults and riotous assemblies, and for the more speedy
>   and effectual punishing the rioters' actually contained this warning:
>
> > "Our sovereign Lord the King chargeth and commandeth all persons,
> >     being assembled, immediately to disperse themselves, and peaceably to
> >     depart to their habitations, or to their lawful business, upon the
> >     pains contained in the act made in the first year of King George, for
> >     preventing tumults and riotous assemblies. God save the King."
>
> ***"VENT ONE’S SPLEEN"*** verbal phrase [1641]: To let loose one’s anger,
>   displeasure, malice, or ill-humor on another; to release one’s
>   emotions in a fit of temper; to criticize somebody fiercely and
>   vindictively for one’s own gratification. This expression uses vent in
>   the sense of ‘air’ and spleen in the sense of ‘anger,’ as in Some
>   people see town council meetings as a place where they can vent their
>   spleen.
>
> From [Wordwizard.com](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=23253)

Answer (score 2):

> Give him a good talking to
>
> Have a few words with him (euphemistic understatement of a sort suitable for the fictional Michael Corleone)
>
> Have something to say to him (likewise euphemistic understatement)
>
> Chew him out
>
> Give him a bollocking (British and Irish, considered offensive)
>
> Tell him off
>
> Give him a (severe, real, strong) telling off
>
> Give him a dressing down
>
> Tell him what I think of him.
>
> Chew the ass/arse of him.
>
> Bawl him out.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely informal (but so is every other suggestion here so far)...

> [Tell it like it is](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Tell+it+like+it+is)  *- **speak frankly***
>   *Tell the truth no matter who is criticized or how much it hurts.*
>   *Describe a situation honestly without avoiding any unpleasant details*.

(I've highlighted the first definition as a less informal alternative.)

---

Note that *tell it like it is* fits all contexts where OP's *not hold myself back* might be used. It can, but doesn't necessarily, imply hostility/aggression, whereas *give him a piece of my mind* always does.